# Can I use the numpy normal distribution sampler to efficiently create a sample using few or no loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I would like to generate a sample that follows a normal distribution from M source values each with a standard deviation, with N samples per source value. Can this be done efficiently with numpy arrays?

My desired output is an MxN array. I expected this pseudocode to work, but it fails with an error:

```
import numpy as np

# initial data
M = 100
x = np.arange(M)
y = x**2
y_err = y * 0.1

# sample the data N times per datapoint
N = 1000
N_samples = np.random.normal(loc=y, scale=y_err, size=N)
```

Running this yields a broadcasting error since N and M are not the same:
`ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

I can imagine solutions that use loops, but is there a better/faster method that minimizes the use of loops? For example, many numpy functions are vectorized so I would expect there to be some numpy method that would be faster or at least avoid the use of loops.

Comment: `np.random.normal(loc=y[:,None], scale=y_err[:,None], size=(M,N))`? `np.random` supports broadcasting.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny that yields the same broadcasting error for me. The issue is with `size=(M,N)`; it appears to require that `y` and `y_err` must match both the dimensionality and size of `(M,N)` (i.e., they must be 2D with the same number of values as `(M,N)`). That's why I tried the second method in my answer below (which duplicates the 1D arrays so they are of size `(M,N)`).

Comment: I checked with the provided example where *y* and *y_err* are of size *M*. Please update the code to make the error reproducible.

Comment: Thanks -- this worked in a fresh python instance. Though the walltime is still consistently longer than the loop method below, e.g.:
`M = 100000    N = 1000
Time used by loop method:  4.1068 seconds
Time used by numpy resize/duplicating method:  6.6237 seconds
Time used by broadcast method:  4.6873 seconds`

Comment: I can confirm: the generator api is ~2x faster, the loop version is ~1.08x faster with both apis.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create two methods: one that uses loops, and one that uses numpy functions. However, the numpy method is slower for large arrays, so I am curious as to why this is and whether there is an alternative method.

Method one: loop through each of the M source values and sample N points from that value, and proceed through the whole dataset so that the numpy sampler is used M times:

```
# initialize the sample array
y_sampled = np.zeros([M, N])

for i in range(M):
    y_sampled[i] = prng.normal(loc=y[i], scale=y_err_abs[i], size=num_samples)
```

Method two: use numpy's vectorized methods on an adjusted dataset, wherein the source data is duplicated to be an MxN array, on which the numpy sampler is applied once

```
# duplicate the source data and error arrays horizontally N times
y_dup = np.repeat(np.vstack(y), N,axis=1)
y_err_dup = np.repeat(np.vstack(y_err), N, axis=1)

# apply the numpy sampler once on the entire 2D array
y_sampled = np.random.normal(loc=y_dup, scale=y_err_dup, size=(M,N))
```

I expected the second method to be faster since the sampler is applied only once, albeit on a 2D array. The walltime is similar for small arrays (`M = 100`) but different by a factor of ~2x for larger arrays (`M = 1E5`). Timing:

```
M = 100    N = 1000
Time used by loop method:  0.0156 seconds
Time used by numpy resize/duplicating method:  0.0199

M = 100000    N = 1000
Time used by loop method:  3.9298 seconds
Time used by numpy resize/duplicating method:  7.3371 seconds
```

I would expect there to be a built-in method to sample N times, instead of duplicating the dataset N times, but these methods work.